# What is the best way to do interface to support iPhone 4, 5, 6, 6+?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, ios8

So I've been doing my interfaces with setting frames based on device. So I have two options - iPhone 4 and iPhone 5, and sometimes iPad.

So I had to position everything twice or three times manually and forget about it.

But now I need to support two new devices, with different resolutions - what should I do?

Do I use Autolayout and figure out some constants that should be same on all devices? But that can't feel good and look great on all devices.

What do you think?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create Universal App for iPhone 6, 6 plus ,iPhone 4,iPhone4s,iphone5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758603/how-to-create-universal-app-for-iphone-6-6-plus-iphone-4-iphone4s-iphone5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple recently announced something which they call **Adaptive UI** - an iOS 8 feature - designed to solve the problem I think you're trying to describe. That might be worth looking into.

Adaptive UI is essentially constraint-based (as you mentioned in your question).

A good explanation can be found here: http://www.imore.com/adaptive-ui-ios-8-explained

Hope this helped and good luck!

Loic

Answer (score 0):

For simple, relatively static content, xib files and auto layout do the job.
If you want to have top-notch user experience, dynamic ui, etc. the best option is to construct the user interface programmatically once you've prototyped your ideas in a xib file.  When I first went down that route, I was dreading it but it is surprisingly easy all things considered.